# Invitations API returns 401 Access token validation failure. Invalid audience

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an MSDN subscription linked to my Personal account. I am trying to write and Web Application which can invite users users using the Invitation API, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations.

I tried to get an token using the Client Credentials flow and then call the above API but getting an invalid audience error. I checked the token and the aud claim is set to 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 which i think is Graph API. I set the Scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default while getting the token

Can some one help me what is that i am doing wrongly or is this scenario not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying with your personal account which is not supported at this moment as you could see on screenshot below:

[image]

You could have a look on [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

I have tried below way and worked for me:

***`Request:`***

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "kironTest@email.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com",
  "userType":"Guest"
}
```

***`Response:`***

[image]

Make sure your token has required permission like  below:

[image]

You could check your permission here https://jwt.io/

Hope that would help.

Comment: How did you get the above token? For me when i use Client credentials in Postman, the aud is not getting populate with graph.microsoft.om

Comment: I got token using client_credentials protocol and as you seen it has required permission as well. Additionally as you used /.Default as scope make sure you are using v2.0 on auth request.

Comment: I was using and auth endpoint for getting access token. changed it to token endpoint and works now Thanks